# linebreak fails for long lines in list of figures

Tags: line-breaking

When lines becoms long and there are many ~-characters (eg for citing) latex fails to break the line in the list of figures and prints into the margin. any ideas how to "force" a break before the margin?

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{Long  Long  Long  Long Long  Long  Long  Long Long Long Long~Long~Long~Long/Long}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Long  Long  Long  Long Long  Long  Long  Long Long Long Long~Long~Long~Long}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Short}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you be clearer what you want to happen. The _only_ reason for using `~` rather than `  `  is to _prevent_ line breaks.

Comment: shure. but it's to prevent line breaks between exactly two words like "page~7". if "page~7" at the end of one line is  too long, latex should break the line before. in the example it totaly doesn't break and prints the text into the margin.

Comment: yes but is `Long~Long~Long~Long` really representative that doesn't give latex any options, `long` isn't hyphenatable and `~` doesn't break.

Comment: Two options for me: either having a shorter caption in the list of figure possible with `\caption[Short description]{Long description}` where the short description will appear in the list of figures and the long in the document, or having the same description and force break lines with ` \\ ` somewhere in your caption and find the good option for the `hyperref` package. You may also need the `caption` package.

Comment: Actually using `\newline` in the "short" description seems to work pretty well to force a line break.

Comment: i'll try to create an more detailed minimal example. the problem is, that i need to include a part of my library and many style stuff to reconstruct the exact text-parts and the used margin that create my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a bit of glue to allow more stretch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\@tocrmarg{2.55em plus 3em}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\caption{Long  Long  Long  Long Long  Long  Long  Long Long Long Long~Long~Long~Long/Long}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Long  Long  Long  Long Long  Long  Long  Long Long Long Long~Long~Long~Long}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Short}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I played around with your idea and if I add another `~` before the already existing ones I got the same problem as previously. Is there a way to adapt your values for not having this kind of surprise or do we have to always check and adapt "manually"?

Comment: @LudovicC. I was reasonably cautious in only giving 3em of extra stretch you could say `plus \textwidth` but that would allow the lines to be arbitrarily short.  Unless you are doing automated runs of thousands of documents it's probably better to let some fail and force a short toc entry to be provided in `\caption[..]` rather than make it silently accept anything

Comment: Thanks, that might spare me a lot of "renaming" of my captions.